# multiple language get data entity asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I use more than one language on my site. I pull data in languages ​​from different rows. For example, I pull the Turkish one from TURKISH_counter_title and the Spanish one from the SPAIN_counter_title row. So I want to extract data from different rows in the same table according to the language. How can I do this parsing?

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     Home home = new Home();
     var dbCounter = db__.Counter.ToList();

     foreach (var item in dbCounter)
     {
         home.Counter_Datas.Add(new Home.CounterData()
                                    {
                                        id = item.ID,
                                        Counter_Title = item.TURKISH_counter_title,
                                    });
    }
}
```

[image]